# "ng build --prod --base-href=/App_name/ --env=prod" throwing Error

Tags: angular, iis, angular6, publish

I want to publish my angular app in local iis but When i run below command it will throw error

> ng build --prod --base-href=/App_name/ --env=prod

ERROR in Error: Template parse errors:
'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

FYO : 
1) normal "ng build" and "ng serve" is running fine.
2) AppHeaderCompo is also declared inside app.module

Answer (score 0):

These are the 5 steps I perform when I got such an error.

1. Are you sure the name is correct? (also check the selector defined in the component)
2. Declare the component in a module?
3. If it is in another module, export the component?
4. If it is in another module, import that module?
5. Restart the cli?